# BeautifulSoup not finding all tr tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am at a complete loss here.I am attempting to pull a table from the following url https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-appearances-fielding.shtml.

On this page, there are two tables. The first is the Team Appearances and the second is Player Appearances.

The following code snippet lets me get the html of the page no problem.

```
url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-appearances-fielding.shtml'
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Everything checks out. When I try and parse to get the header information, I have no trouble. To do that, I am using:

```
header = soup.find_all('tr', attrs ={"class": "thead"})
header
```

What is happening here is that it is only printing the first time that this appears, which is from the Team Appearances table and not both.

```
[<tr class="thead">
 <th aria-label="Tm" class="sort_default_asc show_partial_when_sorting center" data-stat="team_ID">Tm</th>
 <th aria-label="G_team" class="center" data-stat="G_team"></th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_all" data-tip="All games played">G</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Started" class="center" data-stat="GS" data-tip="Games Started">GS</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_batting" data-tip="Games appeared in the batting order,&lt;br&gt;but may not have batted.">Batting</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_defense" data-tip="Games in lineup at a defensive position.">Defense</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_p_app" data-tip="Games in lineup or announced as a pitcher">P</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_c" data-tip="Games in lineup as a catcher">C</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_1b" data-tip="Games in lineup as a first baseman">1B</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_2b" data-tip="Games in lineup as a second baseman">2B</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_3b" data-tip="Games in lineup as a third baseman">3B</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_ss" data-tip="Games in lineup as a shortstop">SS</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_lf_app" data-tip="Games in lineup as a left fielder">LF</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_cf_app" data-tip="Games in lineup as a center fielder">CF</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_rf_app" data-tip="Games in lineup as a right fielder">RF</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_of_app" data-tip="Games in lineup as an outfielder">OF</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_dh" data-tip="Games in lineup as a designated hitter">DH</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_ph" data-tip="Games in lineup as a pinch hitter&lt;br&gt;May have played another position as well.">PH</th>
 <th aria-label="Games Played" class="center" data-stat="G_pr" data-tip="Games in lineup as a pinch runner&lt;br&gt;May have played another position as well.">PR</th>
 </tr>]
```

When I examine the html of the page, the Player Appearances table also has this class so I am unsure why both aren't populating. Additionally, if I change the code to something like

```
table = soup.find_all('tr', attrs ={"class": "full_table"})
table
```

which fits the class of the actual data, I am getting nothing return.

I have been working this for sometime now and am a loss. Am I just overlooking something simple here, or what? Any help and insight is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The other `<tr class="thead">` elements are all inside an HTML comment which starts at line 688.

Comment: Ah, I see that when I few the source in Safari with the color coding but that wasn't as evident in Jupyter or on Chrome. I'm relative new to all of the webscraping with Python still and this is something I hadn't experienced before. Is there a way to still pull this out and I just need to look into how to pull stuff out of comments?

Comment: Yeah, I only noticed because of the highlighting in Firefox myself :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. I found a way to have it read through the comment and I have what I need. Now to data frame is and be good to go! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Maybe you can post your "way to have it read through the comment" as an answer? Other users might be helped by it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the comments with `comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))`, then parse the tables within those.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

# Get list of tables with pandas    
url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-appearances-fielding.shtml"
tables = pd.read_html(url)


# then pull out comments and get the tables within those
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

for each in comments:
    if '<table' in each:
        tables.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
```